# Problem bringing data on a Next.js13 project with mongoDb on vercel deploy

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, vercel, next.js13

I have this project that brings posts from different users while it works fine on localhost, there is a problem when I update that project to vercel, the only time that it will bring all post is when is deployed, after that on the main page where all the post are supposed to be rendered, it won't update. However, it will create the post on mongodb and I can see the post on the userprofile (users have the ability to see all their posts on their page) and I can edit them and delete them just fine and it will also update the mongo db, however the main feed won't even update! here is my code

the Prompt cards should be updated here bringing all post
//

```
"use client"

import {useState , useEffect} from "react"
import PromptCard from "./PromptCard"


const PromptCardList = ({ data, handleTagClick }) => {
  return (
    <div className="mt-16 prompt_layout">
    {data.map((post) => (
      <PromptCard
        key={post._id}
        post={post}
        handleTagClick={handleTagClick}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
  )
}


const Feed = () => {
 
  const [allPosts, setAllPosts] = useState([])
  //search states 
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("")
  const [searchTimeout, setSearchTimeout] = useState(null);
  const [searchedResults, setSearchedResults] = useState([]);



 
  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/api/prompt");
    const data = await response.json();

    setAllPosts(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  
     const filterPrompts = (searchtext) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(searchtext, "i"); 
    return allPosts.filter(
      (item) =>
        regex.test(item.creator.username) ||
        regex.test(item.tag) ||
        regex.test(item.prompt)
    );
  };
  
    const handleSearchChange = (e) => {
    clearTimeout(searchTimeout);
    setSearchText(e.target.value);

    // debounce method
    setSearchTimeout(
      setTimeout(() => {
        const searchResult = filterPrompts(e.target.value);
        setSearchedResults(searchResult);
      }, 500)
    );
  };
  
    const handleTagClick = (tagName) => {
    setSearchText(tagName);

    const searchResult = filterPrompts(tagName);
    setSearchedResults(searchResult);
  };

   useEffect(() => {
    // This effect will run on every mount and re-mount of the component
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);
  return (
    <section className="feed">
      <form className="relative w-full flex-center">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Busca una etiqueta o un nombre de usuario"
          value={searchText}
          onChange={handleSearchChange}
          required
          className="search_input peer"
        />
      </form>

     {/* All Prompts */}
      {searchText ? (
        <PromptCardList
          data={searchedResults}
          handleTagClick={handleTagClick}
        />
      ) : (
        <PromptCardList data={allPosts} handleTagClick={handleTagClick} />
      )}
    </section>
  );
};
      
export default Feed
```

and here is the route  for it
//

```
import { connectToDB } from "@utils/database"
import Prompt from "@models/prompt";


export const GET = async (request) => {
  try {
    await connectToDB();

    const prompts = await Prompt.find({}).populate('creator')
    
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(prompts), {
      status:200
    })

  } catch (error) {
    return new Response("Fallo al traer todas las prompts", { status:500})
  }
}
```

Just as a reminder remember that the user post works just fine so I might as well share you the code in case you see something that I don't, the post rendered in the user profile works just fine and update immediately
//

```
"use client"

import { useState,useEffect } from "react"
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"

import Profile from "@components/Profile"

const MyProfile = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const { data: session } = useSession();
    const [allPost , setAllPosts] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
   
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/users/${session?.user.id}/posts`)
      const data = await response.json()
      setAllPosts(data)
    }

    if(session?.user.id) fetchPosts();
 }, [])
  
  
  const handleEdit = (post) => {
  router.push(`/update-prompt?id=${post._id}`)
}
  const handleDelete = async (post) => {
    const hasConfirmed = confirm("Confirmas que quieres eliminar esta prompt?");

    if (hasConfirmed) {
      try {
        await fetch(`/api/prompt/${post._id.toString()}`,
          {
            method: "DELETE"
          });
        
        const filteredPost = allPost.filter((p) => p._id !== post._id)
        setAllPosts(filteredPost)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
    
  }
  return (
    <Profile
      name="Mi"
      desc="Bienvenido a tu perfil personal!"
      data={allPost}
      handleEdit={handleEdit}
      handleDelete={handleDelete}
    />
  )
}

export default MyProfile`
```

```
import React from 'react'
import PromptCard from './PromptCard'



const Profile = ({name , desc , data, handleEdit , handleDelete}) => {
  return (
    <section className='w-full'>
      <h1 className='head_text text-left'>
        <span className='babyblue_gradient'>{name} Perfil</span> 
      </h1>
      <p className='desc text-left'>{desc}</p>
      <div className="mt-10 prompt_layout">
    {data.map((post) => (
      <PromptCard
        key={post._id}
        post={post}
        handleEdit={() => handleEdit && handleEdit(post)}
        handleDelete={()=> handleDelete && handleDelete(post)}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
   </section>
  )
}

export default Profile
```

//

lastly here is the profile route for bringing user posts which works fine

//

```
import { connectToDB } from "@utils/database"
import Prompt from "@models/prompt";


export const GET = async (request,{params}) => {
  try {
    await connectToDB();

    const prompt = await Prompt.findById(params.id).populate('creator')
    if(!prompt) return new Response ("Prompt no encontrado", {status:404})
    
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(prompt), {
      status:200
    })
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response("Fallo al traer todas las prompts", { status:500})
  }
}
```

the database updates automatically on deploy, I have done several deploys so I know it gets connected, the problem is that get all post won't update after the initial deploy

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).